# Find best fit function for different data set with errors

Tags: fitting, dataset

I have the following 3 data sets for the same quantity with errors as shown in the figure in different colors. How to find the best fit function of 1) each data set separately 2) combined of the 3 data set.
Suppose I find the best fit function of each data set separately; then how to combine the three best-fit functions correctly so that I can have a single fit function. Which method will give the more accurate results; finding one single fit function for all the data sets or finding separately each and then adding them up? How I would check the accuracy.

```
ListPlot[{{Around[0.2, 0.1], Around[1, 0.1], Around[2, 0.2], 
   Around[3, 0.3]}, {Around[0.5, 0.1], Around[2.5, 0.1], 
   Around[3.5, 0.2], Around[3.5, 0.3]}, {Around[0.8, 0.1], 
   Around[1.5, 0.1], Around[2.8, 0.2], Around[1.8, 0.3], 
   Around[5, 0.5]}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: There is no general "best fit function". You have to specify a family of valid functions . E.g. you could ask for the best fit linear function in the least square sense.

Comment: @DanielHuber, Can you try this here. Do you mean for each individual case? Can you explain why a general function is not possible?

Comment: To find a fit, either for each dataset, or for all of them together, you would use either `LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit`. However, your questions touch upon basic fitting concepts, rather than their implementation in Mathematica. I recommend that you ask in [the statistics forum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) first.

Comment: If these data are real measurements, you have vital background information. Use this.
From the data as shown, my conclusion is: combining them is a waste of time.

Comment: @Romke Bontekoe, The only background information is that it's measurements of the same physical quantity by different experiments.

Comment: This question might be better asked as a conceptual question (rather than about specific coding) at CrossValidated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as there are a variety of methods that might meet your objectives.  For example, there would be "mixed models" (essentially regression where there is more than one source of error) and functional data analysis.

Comment: @JimB: Okay, but the stats.stackeschange.com is not so active and the people don't so quickly reply there as on Mathematica.

Comment: If you want the expertise, it just might take longer.  Just write the question so that it grabs someone's attention.

Comment: I see you've already asked the question essentially simultaneously on CrossValidated:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569159/find-best-fit-function-for-different-data-set-with-errors.  It's best to let folks know that at all those forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
data = {
  {Around[0.2, 0.1], Around[1, 0.1],   Around[2, 0.2],   Around[3, 0.3]},
  {Around[0.5, 0.1], Around[2.5, 0.1], Around[3.5, 0.2], Around[3.5, 0.3]}, 
  {Around[0.8, 0.1], Around[1.5, 0.1], Around[2.8, 0.2], Around[1.8, 0.3], Around[5, 0.5]}
};

models =
  LinearModelFit[
     (* extract the central values to fit *)
     # /. a_Around :> a["Value"],
     (* use a quadratic model for the fits *)
     {1, x, x^2}, x,
     (* use the inverse of the uncertainties as weights in the fit *)
     Weights -> (# /. a_Around :> 1/a["Uncertainty"]) 
  ]& /@ data
```

[image: FittedModel results for the three separate data sets]

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, Axes -> False],
 Plot[Evaluate@Through[models[x]], {x, 0, 5}],
 PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: scatter plot of data overlaid with the fitted model plots]

Comment: Interesting! The blue and orange look perfect; however, the green is not so well. Anyway, I will further improve this. Further, I want to know is that how to find that these fit functions can also rightly predict the 1 sigma error of each data point. 2nd, how to find a single function out of the three?

Comment: I am trying your suggested method on the following data, but it doesn't work:  data1 ={{1.916, 0.352, 0.04}, {2.076, 0.432, 0.019}, {2.25, 0.494, 
  0.018}, {2.44, 0.448, 0.016}, {2.73, 0.52, 0.015}, {2.976, 0.456, 
  0.012}, {3.26, 0.538, 0.012}, {3.532, 0.374, 0.011}} . Can you please look at this?

Comment: @SciJewel What do the three numbers mean in each point?

Comment: The first one is the x-axis, 2nd is the data point (Y-axis), and the 3rd one is the error on the data point.

Comment: @SciJewel Try `LinearModelFit[data1[[All, ;;2]], {1, x, x^2}, x, Weights -> 1/data1[[All, 3]]]`

Comment: thanks, it worked. Further, how can I test that this is the best fit function that can describe the data well

Comment: @SciJewel you can look into "goodness of fit" measures, but, In short, you can't. You need to choose a sensible model yourself, in the basis of what you know about the physical processes that generated the data. No algorithm can replace that.

Comment: @SciJewel Additionally, if my answer solves your problem, you can indicate that by formally accepting it. Click the gray check mark beside it to accept it.

Comment: Done! Further, is this possible to retrieve the uncertainty of each data point back from the fit function?

Comment: @SciJewel Have a look at the statistical properties you can extract from a fitted model function in the Details and Options section of the documentation of LinearModelFit. Perhaps you are looking for `"MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervals"` or `"MeanPredictionConfidenceIntervalTable"`?